# Position DIV relative to fixed DIV with variable content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 2 DIV's. The first (blue background) has a fixed position. The second (yellow background) should be positioned below the first. The content of the first DIV is variable, and therefore has a variable height. But I want the second DIV to move up or down, relative to the height of the first DIV.

The behaviour of the second DIV now, is not ok. It 'hides' behind the first DIV, but I want the second DIV to begin, where the first DIV ends, no matter what height the first DIV is.

I can easily add some css to the second DIV (padding-top: 100px, or something), but I can't use a set height, because the height of the first DIV is variable (try changing the width of the browser window, to see what I mean)

How can I get the second DIV to change it's vertical position, relative to the height of the first DIV?

```html
<div style="background-color:#00f; color:#fff; position:fixed; height:auto; width:94%; ">
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:#ff3; color:#000; padding:10px; display:inline-block; width:90%; height:auto;">
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once `position:sticky` is more widespread, you can use that.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 8px
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#00f; color:#fff; position:sticky; top:8px; height:auto; width:94%; ">
  start of first
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
  end of first
</div>
<div style="background-color:#ff3; color:#000; padding:10px; display:inline-block; width:90%; height:auto;">
  start of second
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  end of second
</div>
```

But since this works (currently) only in Firefox, what you can do for now is use `fixed` and a bit of JavaScript to set the top margin of the second div to the height of the first.

```js
document.getElementById('second').style.marginTop =
  document.getElementById('first').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 8px
}
```

```html
<div id="first" style="background-color:#00f; color:#fff; position:fixed; top:8px; height:auto; width:94%; ">
  start of first
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
  end of first
</div>
<div id="second" style="background-color:#ff3; color:#000; padding:10px; display:inline-block; width:90%; height:auto;">
  start of second
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  end of second
</div>
```

Comment: Position: sticky does the trick, position wise. But I still need the first DIV to stay put, and the second DIV to move behind it, when scrolling.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I see it wobbles a bit when you scroll. How about this then, with `top` the same value as the body margin. (You can change both values to what you need of course.)

Comment: Because the first DIV has a variable height (depending on the amount of content, and width of the browser window), I can't use css 'top' with a set value. The whole thing needs to be responsive.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. My bad. I made an error when copying your code to my local file. Thank you so much. You rule! Problem solved :-)

Comment: OK! Note, however, that the first remark in my answer still stands; this doesn't work in all browsers. Currently, not even in the _majority_ of browsers. So handle with care.

Comment: hmmm... that is a problem. I only tested it in the one browser (Firefox) that handles it the right way. Unfortunately Chrome and Explorer are not playing nice. So that means back to the drawing table for me, because the solution I'm after needs to work cross-browser, not just in Firefox :-(

Comment: If all else fails, I guess I must set a save margin, for the second DIV and set the position back to 'fixed', on the first DIV. This will create a big white gab, in some cases, but that's less of a problem than a solution that only works with Firefox. The differences in browser behaviour never fail to amaze me...

Comment: You can use a bit of JavaScript to set the top margin of the second div to the height of the first (see my edited answer). But then if you want to be thorough, you also should keep into account that the height of the first one can change during the lifetime of the page (for instance when the user resizes the window).

Comment: I think I've got it. With the help of jquery and a small plugin called 'jquery.sticky.js', I now have a working example that performs well in Firefox, Chrome and Explorer. I have posted the code as an answer [to my own question :-)] Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Can float do the trick? So both div's use float:left. And add a clear:both to the second div. see:
https://jsfiddle.net/rzL7u8xe/

```html
<div style="background-color:#00f; color:#fff; height:auto; width:94%; float:left">
 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
</div>
<div style="background-color:#ff3; color:#000; padding:10px; display:inline-block; width:90%; height:auto; float:left; clear:both;">
```

Comment: This also resolves the position issue, but doesn't make the first DIV stay on it's place. Think of the first DIV like a menu (always visible) and the second DIV as the page content.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>fixed position</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garand/sticky/master/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //refresh page on browser resize
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
  window.RT = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
  }, 200);
});
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 10000px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #header {
      background: #00f;
      color: white;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.6em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2%;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      width:100%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div>1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#ff3; color:#000; padding:2%; display:inline-block; width:95%; height:auto;">
    2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222 2222
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This snippet only seems to work in Gecko, not in Chrome or IE.

Comment: Perhaps due to local security settings, or something. But I have tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE, and this works in all of them. Maybe not from the snippet function (Run code snippet) on this website, but when you copy this code, and save it as a local HTML-file, everything works fine. At least overhere it does.

Comment: Oh, I get an error. "SEC7112: Script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/garand/sticky/master/jquery.sticky.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch" This is in IE11. Do you have different settings in your version of IE?

Comment: I also downloaded the jquery.sticky.js file to my local disk. And called that file in my HTML, instead of the online github url. This probably causes the error you get in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this similar one issue, my navbar were fixed and the next placed div positioned relative were starting from top instead of relatively after fixed `<nav>` height.

Let me show you in source for your better consideration.

```
<header>
    <nav class="position-fixed" style="height:100px;">
        ....logo with some menus and icons.
    </nav>
    <div class="position-relative" style="height:200px;">
        ...background banner and other stuffs
    </div>
</header>
```

so below said things were happening...

1. `<header>` height were showing 200px instead of 300px
2. because div placed after `<nav>` were starting from top zero.

So, I do this below said arrangements to view the div from top next to above fixed `<nav>`.

```css
.commonDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  position: fixed;
  background: orange;
  width: calc(100% - 16.5px);
}

.dummyDiv {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.third {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="commonDiv dummyDiv">
    <div class="first">
      I am first and I am fixed
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second commonDiv">
    I am second and I am relative to dummy
  </div>
  <div class="third commonDiv">
    I am third and I am relative to second
  </div>
</div>
```

In `CSS` you can see that, I have managed the `<div class="first">` element width, because it's position is `fixed` and fixed position element directly point to viewport or you can say `DOM` page instead of it's parent tag or element like `absolute` (so, this is the major difference here between position `fixed` and `absolute`).

So, I keep that fixed `div/nav` inside a relative div class named `"dummyDiv"` to manage the height for next upcoming relative `div`,

people wise ways can be many, and I have managed this scenario like above, hope it will help many one.